# File separator in windows makefile

Tags: windows, makefile, nmake

This may have been asked before but recently I came across a windows make file which had both type of file separators.
E.g. - following two lines from that make file :

```
SRC = src/test.cpp
@mkdir lib\$(HOST) > NUL
```

from when does windows have started supporting both type of file separators ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Windows expert, by any stretch.  However, the basic Windows file APIs all support forward slash (except in some odd situations like unicode character support, I guess) as directory separators.  Thus it works correctly in *most* situations.  When people write makefiles I always urge them to always use forward slashes for everything, until/unless it's proven that it won't work in a particular instance.

You can easily find lots of discussion of this via Google.